# How to monitor Apache Flink in AWS EMR (ElasticMapReduce)?

Tags: apache-flink, terraform, amazon-emr

I currently have Flink setup and have a Job running on EMR and I'm now trying to add monitoring by sending metrics off to prometheus.

I have come across an issue with running Flink on EMR. I'm using Terraform to provision EMR (I run ansible after to download and run a job).  Out the box, it does not look like EMR's Flink distribution includes the optional jars (flink-metrics-prometheus, flink-cep, etc).

Looking at Flink's documentation, it says

> "In order to use this reporter you must copy `/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-1.6.1.jar` into the `/lib` folder of your Flink distribution"
>   https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/metrics.html#prometheuspushgateway-orgapacheflinkmetricsprometheusprometheuspushgatewayreporter

But when logging into the EMR master node, neither /etc/flink or /usr/lib/flink has a directory called `opts` and i can not see `flink-metrics-prometheus-1.6.1.jar` anywhere.

I know Flink has other optional libs you'd usually have to copy if you want to use them such as flink-cep, but I'm not sure how to do this when using EMR.

This is the exception i get, which I beleive is because it can not find the metrics jar in its classpath.

```java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl.<init>(MetricRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.createMetricRegistry(ClusterEntrypoint.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:276)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:227)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$0(ClusterEntrypoint.java:191)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:137)
```

EMR resource in terraform

```
  resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr_flink" {
  name          = "ce-emr-flink-arn"
  release_label = "emr-5.20.0" # 5.21.0 is not found, could be a region thing
  applications  = ["Flink"]

  ec2_attributes {
    key_name                          = "ce_test"
    subnet_id                         = "${aws_subnet.ce_test_subnet_public.id}"
    instance_profile                  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn}"
    emr_managed_master_security_group = "${aws_security_group.allow_all_vpc.id}"
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${aws_security_group.allow_all_vpc.id}"
    additional_master_security_groups  = "${aws_security_group.external_connectivity.id}"
    additional_slave_security_groups  = "${aws_security_group.external_connectivity.id}"
  }

  ebs_root_volume_size = 100
  master_instance_type = "m4.xlarge"
  core_instance_type   = "m4.xlarge"
  core_instance_count  = 2

  service_role = "${aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.arn}"

  configurations_json = <<EOF
[
  {
    "Classification": "flink-conf",
    "Properties": {
        "parallelism.default": "8",
        "state.backend": "RocksDB",
        "state.backend.async": "true",
        "state.backend.incremental": "true",
        "state.savepoints.dir": "file:///savepoints",
        "state.checkpoints.dir": "file:///checkpoints",
        "web.submit.enable": "true",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.class": "org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporter",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.host": "${aws_instance.monitoring.private_ip}",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.port": "9091",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName": "ce-test",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.randomJobNameSuffix": "true",
        "metrics.reporter.promgateway.deleteOnShutdown": "false"
    }
  }
]
EOF
}
```

I suspect i may have to download the Jar in the bootstrap stage, but wanted to check this first, and see if there's any examples of this being done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Terraform, but note that you typically need to provision (set up jars) on both the master and the slaves in EMR. One way to figure out where EMR thinks jars should go is to log onto a slave when a job is running, do `ps auxwww | grep java`, find the `TaskManager` process, look at the jars added to the classpath when it launched, and find where those are located on the server. Or at least that worked for me in the past.

Comment: In EMR at least there was no jar running on the host (maybe inside a yarn container though) except wherever the job manager was running. Adding the optional flink-metrics jar to the node with the job manager (the master node) seemed to do the trick even though the slaves didnt have the jar.

Comment: OK, good to know. Though when a job is running on a slave, there will be a task manager process running (unless you have fewer task managers than slaves, I guess).

Comment: I think task managers run inside containers when running on yarn though, right? So you wouldn't see it with ps aux? Whereas job manager runs outside of yarn if i remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

I've select the EMR release emr-5.24.0 and I monitoring with the influxdb .jar with suceed.

I've copy the .jar file to `/usr/lib/flink/lib` folder and restart the Flink cluster with the following bash command (with sudo permission).

```sh
/usr/lib/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh && /usr/lib/flink/bin/stop-cluster.sh
```

I assume that you can solve your question with the same steps for prometheus

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-11-17 ~]$ cd /usr/lib/flink/opt/flink-metrics-
flink-metrics-datadog-1.8.0.jar     flink-metrics-influxdb-1.8.0.jar    flink-metrics-slf4j-1.8.0.jar
flink-metrics-graphite-1.8.0.jar    flink-metrics-prometheus-1.8.0.jar  flink-metrics-statsd-1.8.0.jar


[ec2-user@ip-10-0-11-17 ~]$ ll /usr/lib/flink/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-1.8.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 101984 may 14 19:21 /usr/lib/flink/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-1.8.0.jar


[ec2-user@ip-10-0-11-17 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-11-17 4.14.114-83.126.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 7 02:26:58 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```